# How do you get a fresh checkout every build in CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

Is it possible to tell CruiseControl.NET to perform a fresh checkout with every build? Normally this would seem like the wrong solution, however, it is for our overnight regression test and we need our test cases (in a separate repository) to be freshly checked out with each overnight regression build.

We are running CruiseControl.NET 1.4.4.49. If this feature is available in a later release of CruiseControl.NET, we are willing to update for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [`cleanCopy="true"`](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Subversion_%28svn%29).

Comment: Ah, for some reason I didn't think it would remove the .svn folder from the root. Thanks\